# conglomerate with multi domains: how can we cached customer info from other domain visits without changing all to oauth?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cookies

Would like to find out from the experts in website stack process/behaviour.

We have multiple companies (through acquisitions). All on separate systems standards etc. all with different domains. Ideally all brands on a single ecommerce platform with whitelabel/brands recording users and transactions. not possible due to large legacy base....

Some customers overlap, but for customers on one brand but not yet on the other we want to leverage that insight when they are a visitor e.g.
customer (X1) is member/signed up to Brand X. When X1 visits Brand Y we would like to leverage this basic insight (e.g. we know sex, and potentially propensity to purchase based on other transactions we can anonymise & record)

note: we realise there are key terms, opt in/out, privacy issues to solve. Just wondering if its technically feasible and how.

Behaviour we need

a. record all transactions centrally across brands (new server, simple api allows anonymised customers to be created, and transaction to be recorded for an anonymised set of customer data). This way transactions on brand X can be used to understand propensity to purchase in brand Y. e.g. conglomerate.com holds consolidated list of transactions and mappings of customers of multiple brands.

b. first time: logged in customer X1 of a Brand X calls API to record member which is returned new anonymised central member ID (AX1).  somehow: browser  records AX1 e.g. similar to cookie or oauth session.

c. customer X1 logs into other brand Y (as customer Y1), Brand Y calls API using AX1 and therefore X1 identity is recorded in central repository (X1=Y1=AX1). then when Y1 does transactions on 
    ISSUE: as brand Y is different domain, cannot record cookie.

d. customer X1 visits brand Z as a visitor. as brand Z is part of our group, website can query the central service based on cookie recorded identity (AX1) e.g. AX1 recently did something on Brand X, and that will affect marketing automation for the visitor experience (simplest case: gender )

BUT because of the different domains, cannot have a central cookie or share cookies.
if we have a central server (e.g. conglomerate.com ) this can record cookies, and we have javascript code on each brand that goes to conglomerate.com but redirects back to brand. We still can't share info between the 2 sessions

other ways/thoughts:

- setup our oauth with session cache e.g. leaving user 'logged in' (a' la facebook). Surely this requires all brands to force their users to use oauth rather than existing email logins. we don't want to necessarily change the login technology/setup of all the various brands, have to force users to update their passwords.
- hidden/tiny iframes on each brand which access conglomerate.com to do this 'functionality'   - everything i read, iframes are evil.., and also how do you 'share' e.g. picking up the anonymised recorded ID AX1 stored in the cookie.
- Even with this though, not sure how we share info between redirected page and current page (other than via back-end, but then you still don't have the shared identity of the visitor - until they login)

Note: i get that this is not 100% as mobile device will show differently to  desktop browser. wW assume that given mobile is large majority we can focus on this and ignore failings of desktop v mobile for now.

hope i've described myself, sure there are other flaws in the logic. Really welcome views from experts on how this could be accomplished?

Cheers